Oracle decimal issues with float and number types
We have the following issue.
There is a tool which

process files for each daily report
reads product names and quantity from them,
looks for their prices    in a database table.
it inserts the quantity and prices/qty into the detail table
It inserts sum of the detailed costs into parent table daily (each day has a parent and this parent has a details table)

The result is something like this (each row represents one day):

More than 10% of the data is like above.
All the fields in the stored procedure, which makes the calculations and inserts the data into the tables, are number type variables, but the fields in the tables are float types.
Now the question, how can I fix this ugly tons of decimal places and tiny differences between the sum of the details and the result of the sum in the parent table?
As I understand this is coming from the conversion to float. Is this correct?
I have two idea to fix it:

change all the number variables to float in the stored procedures
or round up the numbers to 2 decimal places when inserting them into the database

Would any of above solve the problem? Or there is a better way? I can't touch the tables.
Thanks in advance,
Szil.

"... the fields in the tables are float types": that's the problem. Never use floating-point for money. Use DECIMAL.

Does this answer your question? Why not use Double or Float to represent currency?

Thanks guys for the answers.
Unfortunatelly the database is given, I can't alter it, so I have to deal with the float type currencies.
The provided link neither helps me, because as stated above, I can't alter the database. I can alter only the stored procedure which inserts data into the tables.

Internally, a float column is inherently going to contain those discrepancies.  (See the canonical SO question "Is floating-point math broken?".)  Rounding before inserting into the column is not going to help.  It would help (the discrepancies wouldn't be visible) if you could round to two places when displaying the numbers, if that's an option for you.

If the stored procedure is truly the only thing you can alter, then there's truly nothing you can do.  Taking from the first row in your image: the decimal number 14752.07 simply does not exist in double-precision binary floating point.  The closest nearby representable numbers are (approximately) 14752.0699999999997 and 14752.0700000000015.  Similarly, from the next row,  3908.38 doesn't exist, either, with the nearby representable numbers being 3908.37999999999965 and 3908.380000000000109.

Thanks Steve. I wait one day more and if nobody suggest me a working solution, then I will accept your answer.
In the application and output reports these numbers are rounded, as you have suggested. Then it will remain as it is in the database.

There's a completely different phenomenon that miiiiight come into play, since you said you're summing lots of numbers.  When numbers being summed have significantly different magnitudes, it can make a difference which order you add them in, and it can be a good idea to sort them, and to add the smallest (in absolute value) ones first.  See also Kahan summation.  But in your application this is probably not going to make a difference.

Steve,If you convert your comments from yesterday into an answer, then I can accept it as a solution.
